# URL htaccess with php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have a URL that looks like:

```
url.com/profile.php?username=ahmedaaaaa
```

How would I go about converting that URL to:

```
url.com/ahmedaaaaa
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: You could use the Slim Framework to create pretty urls.